# Prepare list of fields for arcpy.TransposeFields_management

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to generate a list of field names to use a input for arcpy.TransposeFields_management.

The list of fields for the transpose needs to be in this format:

```
in_field="VALUE1 VALUE1;VALUE2 VALUE; VALUE3 VALUE3"
```

but the closest I can get is:

```
in_field="VALUE1; VALUE1;VALUE2; VALUE; VALUE3; VALUE3"
```

using code below.

```py
field_names = []
fields = arcpy.ListFields(TabulateArea)
for field in fields:
        field_names.append(field.name)
del field_names[0:2] #Don't need first two fields
a = field_names
b = []
for i in a:
    b.extend([i,I]) #duplicating field names
delimited_list = ' ;'.join(b) # adding semi-colon and space
print(delimited_list)
VALUE_2 ;VALUE_2 ;VALUE_8 ;VALUE_8 ;VALUE_9 ;VALUE_9 ;VALUE_10 ;VALUE_10 ;VALUE_11 ;VALUE_11 ;VALUE_17 ;VALUE_17
```

How can I prepare a list of field names for transpose tool?

Comment: Where did you initialize field_names in line 3? Also, you could condense that down with a list comprehension. a = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(TabulateArea)]. Instead of extending your list in the second for loop, just run through your original list making each element equal to itself x2, i.e. field_names[i] = field_names[i] + field_names[i].

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(TabulateArea)]
fields_duplicated = ["{} {}".format(field, field) for field in fields]
delimited_string = ";".join(fields_duplicated)
print(delimited_string)
```